# How to change table width

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

I am trying to decrease a table width to 700px

the table is underneath < h2>Cart Totals< /h2> and no matter how I apply "width: 700px;" the table will not decrease in size.

http://clients.rocoru.com/trendyheadboards/?page_id=6

Comment: Could you provide a bit of the HTML and CSS code?

Comment: That comes up with "Your cart is currently empty." and no "Cart Totals" header to be seen.

Comment: the table could be inheriting some styling. I haven't taken a look at the css, but you could try `width: 700px !important;`

Comment: Please provide us with some specifics. The definition you gave us so far is too vague, and the link does not show any table. Rgds,

Comment: @AlexBell in order to see his table you have to add a project to the cart ;) But I agree - providing a direct example would be - well - nice?

Comment: Sadly i 'cannot' write bad words on StackOverflow. Something like #f04$@ff!! there is no '< h2>Cart Totals< /h2>' in your freaked out html rendering on page 'fish a link/?page_id=6'. ..

Comment: Sorry guys - you need to add a product to the shopping cart first

Comment: @AdamScott if an answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the following rule in `master.css, line 687`:

```
#costing-container, .shipping {
  width: 980px;
  border-top: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

Your applied the `shipping`class to a tr inside your table, thus stretching it to 980px. If your remove that class or change its width-rule to 700px your table will display like you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Johannes sounds correct, but if you do not want to modify the master.css file, try applying an `id` to the table in question and change the other css to

```
#table_id tr {
    width: 700px !important;
}
```

This should ensure that your styling doesn't shrink other `table` elements.

Comment: Actually this will not work. Applying `width: 700px !important` to the table, will still have the table stretched to 980px. It will work though, if the rule targets the tr elements of said table.